# Chef: How to make Chef apply the instructions against specific nodes in one command only

Tags: ansible, chef-infra

My scenario:

- Have: A cluster of running ec2 instances
- Want: Use configure management tool to set up a running Kubernetes cluster

With Ansible:

- Everything is checked into source control, including:

  - Specification of what I should do against some nodes (e.g. role/playbook...)
  - Mapping of role to node (e.g. the `playbook.yaml` file)
- Next time I want to bootstrap another k8s cluster, I just need to change the *inventory* and call one single command like `ansible-playbook master-playbook.yaml`

With Chef:

- Only specification of what I should do against some nodes (role, recipe, cookbook...) and NOT the mapping of those with some specific nodes
- Next time I want to bootstrap another k8s cluster (given that I have already bootstrapped `chef-client` on those nodes), I have to call `knife ssh <node-pattern> chef-client` on each of the nodes in the cluster

Question: How to make Chef apply the instructions against specific nodes in one command only (like `ansible-playbook master-playbook.yaml`)

Note:

- Writing a `Bash` script to call `knife-ssh` commands sounds like a workaround to me, I prefer a more `Chef`-ish way.

Update:

- I want the command to be generic, like `ansible-playbook master-playbook.yaml` and not something specific like `knife ssh <node-pattern> chef-client`. The reason is that I have tons of Chef projects, many of which I might not touch for months. When I want to bootstrap some of them again, I can't remember the specific `knife ssh <node-pattern> chef-client` command for each node. I just want to memorize a generic Chef command for all projects (like `ansible-playbook master-playbook.yaml` - you can apply this to all projects, and it can bootstrap all the different types of nodes).

Comment: This is really more suited to a Terraform+Ansible than a Ansible+Chef.

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting, can you please elaborate on it?

Answer (score 1):

use a search query string in conjunction with [`knife ssh`](https://docs.chef.io/knife_ssh.html) , see last example in [`knife search` documentation](https://docs.chef.io/knife_search.html):

> To test a search query that will be used in a knife ssh subcommand:
>
> ```
> $ knife search node "role:web NOT name:web03"
> ```
>
> where the query in the previous example will search all servers that have the `web` role, but not on the server named `web03`.
>
> a search query is comprised of two parts: the `key` and the `search pattern`. where `key` is a field name that is found in the JSON description of an indexable object on the Chef server (a role, node, client, environment, or data bag) and `search_pattern` defines what will be searched for, using one of the following search patterns: exact, wildcard, range, or fuzzy matching. Both key and search_pattern are case-sensitive; key has limited support for multiple character wildcard matching using an asterisk ("*") (and as long as it is not the first character).

so you could use the search query string with knife ssh:

```
$ knife ssh "role:web NOT name:web03" "sudo chef-client" -a fqdn
```

Comment: In my scenario, there's "master node" and "agent node". Using your approach, I'll have to use at least 2 `knife ssh` commands. What I want is to use one command only (with Ansible, you can use a single master-playbook to bootstrap both the master and agent nodes with `ansible-playbook master-playbook.yaml). Is there a Chef *built-in* support for this use case?

Comment: @TranTriet: i assume that you have 2 different roles -- **agent** and **master**. you can use a single query string in conjunction to `knife ssh`. for instance, `role:agent and role:master`

Comment: I understand the concept of `role`. But in my case, I use policy group. If I understand your approach correctly, you'll eventually need to use `knife ssh <some-specific-pattern> <command>`. This is not what I want since it is not generic and can't be used for all projects. I will have to use the correct `pattern` for each project. I want something that will work for all projects like `ansible-playbook master-playbook.yaml`

Comment: @TranTriet: you can assist different roles to a single node, that might ease your pain (or you can use any index attribute). but regarding your question, this is how it is done -- whether we like it or not :)